# Checking if current time is in a given interval, GOLANG

Tags: go, time

I am trying to find a way to check if the current time is in a given interval, where start and end are given (eventually) by a user.

I have been trying by using the After and Before from the Time package after making sure all times are in UTC, but clearly I am doing something wrong.

The code looks similar to this example:

```
func inTimeSpan(start, end, check time.Time) bool {
    return check.After(start) && check.Before(end)
}

func main() {

    now := time.Now()
    newLayout := "15:04"
    ns, _ := time.Parse(newLayout, strconv.Itoa(now.Hour())+":"+strconv.Itoa(now.Minute()))
    srt, _ := time.Parse(newLayout, "23:00")
    end, _ := time.Parse(newLayout, "05:00")

    fmt.Println("1 : ", inTimeSpan(srt, end, ns))
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a clean solution which is immune from time zone issues. In my context, I run a function in a concurrent timer thread and it calls this function every 5 minutes to check the time against the given range.

Note that you should use whole minutes only for this to work. While I haven't tested it, I think the `time.Kitchen` layout will strip seconds during the time conversions. There is no need to specify seconds as the selector will take every time in the range except the exact end time.

There is no accounting for midnight but I didn't need that functionality. If you wanted that you could test

```
if end.Before(start) {

if timeNow.After(start) {
   return false 
}

if timeNow.After(end) {
   return true
}
return false
} else {

....
}
```

Here is my function as it is.

```
func stringToTime(str string) time.Time {
    tm, err := time.Parse(time.Kitchen, str)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to decode time:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Time decoded:", tm)
    return tm
}

func isInTimeRange() bool {

    startTimeString := "06:00AM"  // "01:00PM"

    endTimeString := "06:05AM"

    t := time.Now()

    zone, offset := t.Zone()

    fmt.Println(t.Format(time.Kitchen), "Zone:", zone, "Offset UTC:", offset)

    timeNowString := t.Format(time.Kitchen)

    fmt.Println("String Time Now: ", timeNowString)

    timeNow := stringToTime(timeNowString)

    start := stringToTime(startTimeString)

    end := stringToTime(endTimeString)

    fmt.Println("Local Time Now: ", timeNow)

    if timeNow.Before(start) {
        return false
    }

    if timeNow.Before(end) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Output

> What's the time, Mr Wolf?
>
> 10:58AM Zone: ACST Offset UTC: 34200
>
> String Time Now:  10:58AM
>
> Time decoded: 0000-01-01 10:58:00 +0000 UTC
>
> Time decoded: 0000-01-01 11:00:00 +0000 UTC
>
> Time decoded: 0000-01-01 11:05:00 +0000 UTC
>
> Local Time Now:  0000-01-01 10:58:00 +0000 UTC
>
> What's the time, Mr Wolf?
>
> 11:03AM Zone: ACST Offset UTC: 34200
>
> String Time Now:  11:03AM
>
> Time decoded: 0000-01-01 11:03:00 +0000 UTC
>
> Time decoded: 0000-01-01 11:00:00 +0000 UTC
>
> Time decoded: 0000-01-01 11:05:00 +0000 UTC
>
> Local Time Now:  0000-01-01 11:03:00 +0000 UTC
>
> Time to eat you!

Answer (score 12):

EDIT: It was wrong initially, sorry about that. Fixed version, and also the range now is inclusive. Check also [Mickael V. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093676/checking-if-current-time-is-in-a-given-interval-golang/58960752#58960752) as adding time make sense too.

```
func inTimeSpan(start, end, check time.Time) bool {
    if start.Before(end) {
        return !check.Before(start) && !check.After(end)
    }
    if start.Equal(end) {
        return check.Equal(start)
    }
    return !start.After(check) || !end.Before(check)
}
```

Check it on playground https://play.golang.org/p/CGWqY2AQ-Th

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func inTimeSpan(start, end, check time.Time) bool {
    if start.Before(end) {
        return !check.Before(start) && !check.After(end)
    }
    if start.Equal(end) {
        return check.Equal(start)
    }
    return !start.After(check) || !end.Before(check)
}

func main() {
    test := []struct {
        start string
        end   string
        check string
    }{
        {"23:00", "05:00", "04:00"},
        {"23:00", "05:00", "23:30"},
        {"23:00", "05:00", "20:00"},
        {"10:00", "21:00", "11:00"},
        {"10:00", "21:00", "22:00"},
        {"10:00", "21:00", "03:00"},
        // Additional checks.
        {"22:00", "02:00", "00:00"},
        {"10:00", "21:00", "10:00"},
        {"10:00", "21:00", "21:00"},
        {"23:00", "05:00", "06:00"},
        {"23:00", "05:00", "23:00"},
        {"23:00", "05:00", "05:00"},
        {"10:00", "21:00", "10:00"},
        {"10:00", "21:00", "21:00"},
        {"10:00", "10:00", "09:00"},
        {"10:00", "10:00", "11:00"},
        {"10:00", "10:00", "10:00"},
    }
    newLayout := "15:04"
    for _, t := range test {
        check, _ := time.Parse(newLayout, t.check)
        start, _ := time.Parse(newLayout, t.start)
        end, _ := time.Parse(newLayout, t.end)
        fmt.Println(t.start+"-"+t.end, t.check, inTimeSpan(start, end, check))
    }
}
```

Result:

```
23:00-05:00 04:00 true
23:00-05:00 23:30 true
23:00-05:00 20:00 false
10:00-21:00 11:00 true
10:00-21:00 22:00 false
10:00-21:00 03:00 false
22:00-02:00 00:00 true
10:00-21:00 10:00 true
10:00-21:00 21:00 true
23:00-05:00 06:00 false
23:00-05:00 23:00 true
23:00-05:00 05:00 true
10:00-21:00 10:00 true
10:00-21:00 21:00 true
10:00-10:00 09:00 false
10:00-10:00 11:00 false
10:00-10:00 10:00 true
```

Comment: The last line seems wrong - `inTimeSpan` returns `true` if `check` is before `start` (and therefore *not* between `start` and `end`).

Comment: @Adrian No, that's correct and intentional (unless I misunderstood OP). You have range from 23:00 to 05:00 but there is no date involved. That's the original issue with the code. OP assume 04:00 is between 23:00-05:00 which is correct but time package understands 23:00 as today, and 05:00 as today (instead of next day). If time.Parse would use date you would be correct but then there wouldn't be a problem with comparing times in the first place.

Comment: But to be honest you can achieve the same with just string comparision instead of time package.

Comment: It is actually not correct, I did realized but forgot to write it. The examples results should have been  true, true, false, true, false, false. Anyhow your solution was accepted because it basically helped me solving my problem. Thanks a lot. I also see my original thanks reply is not there …. sorry

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Kamil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55093788/860246), which is ultimately wrong as its own tests show, here is a solution that makes use only of Go's time interface.
The trick, knowing that Go will make `Before` and `After` comparison using time AND date, is to just push the end time to the next day if its time component is "smaller" than the start one. Then the time to check needs to be done the same if it's before the start time.

I took the same test cases and added some significant ones like midnight.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func inTimeSpan(start, end, check time.Time) bool {
    _end := end
    _check := check
    if end.Before(start) {
        _end = end.Add(24 * time.Hour)
        if check.Before(start) {
            _check = check.Add(24 * time.Hour)
        }
    }
    return _check.After(start) && _check.Before(_end)
}

func main() {
    test := []struct {
        start string
        end   string
        check string
    }{
        {"23:00", "05:00", "04:00"},
        {"23:00", "05:00", "23:30"},
        {"23:00", "05:00", "20:00"},
        {"10:00", "21:00", "11:00"},
        {"10:00", "21:00", "22:00"},
        {"10:00", "21:00", "03:00"},
        {"22:00", "02:00", "00:00"},
        {"10:00", "21:00", "10:00"},
        {"10:00", "21:00", "21:00"},
    }
    newLayout := "15:04"
    for _, t := range test {
        check, _ := time.Parse(newLayout, t.check)
        start, _ := time.Parse(newLayout, t.start)
        end, _ := time.Parse(newLayout, t.end)
        fmt.Println(t.start+"-"+t.end, t.check, inTimeSpan(start, end, check))
    }
}
```

Output :

```
23:00-05:00 04:00 true
23:00-05:00 23:30 true
23:00-05:00 20:00 false
10:00-21:00 11:00 true
10:00-21:00 22:00 false
10:00-21:00 03:00 false
22:00-02:00 00:00 true
10:00-21:00 10:00 false
10:00-21:00 21:00 false
```

You will notice on the two last cases that the check is not inclusive for the start time, nor the end time. If you need to change that behavior, you can remediate this by changing the function a little :

```golang
func inTimeSpanEx(start, end, check time.Time, includeStart, includeEnd bool) bool {
    _start := start
    _end := end
    _check := check
    if end.Before(start) {
        _end = end.Add(24 * time.Hour)
        if check.Before(start) {
            _check = check.Add(24 * time.Hour)
        }
    }

    if includeStart {
    _start = _start.Add(-1 * time.Nanosecond)
    }
    if includeEnd {
    _end = _end.Add(1 * time.Nanosecond)
    }

    return _check.After(_start) && _check.Before(_end)
}
```

Extract of the output when calling with `true` for inclusion of start and end :

```
10:00-21:00 10:00 true
10:00-21:00 21:00 true
```

Complete playground here : https://play.golang.org/p/8ig34gmHl71

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func inTimeSpan(start, end, check time.Time) bool {
    start, end = start.UTC(), end.UTC()
    if start.After(end) {
        start, end = end, start
    }
    check = check.UTC()
    return !check.Before(start) && !check.After(end)
}

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    newLayout := "15:04"
    ns, _ := time.Parse(newLayout, strconv.Itoa(now.Hour())+":"+strconv.Itoa(now.Minute()))
    srt, _ := time.Parse(newLayout, "23:00")
    end, _ := time.Parse(newLayout, "05:00")

    fmt.Println(srt, end)
    fmt.Println(ns)
    fmt.Println("1 : ", inTimeSpan(srt, end, ns))
}
```

Output:

```
0000-01-01 23:00:00 +0000 UTC 0000-01-01 05:00:00 +0000 UTC
0000-01-01 20:37:00 +0000 UTC
1 :  true
```

Comment: 20:37 is not between 23:00-05:00, should be false (as long as I understand OP question).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this helps. I have a similar use case where I need to check the given timestamp is between two time.Time.

The below function should work well:

```
func CheckWithinTimeSpan(start, end, check time.Time) bool {
    if check.Equal(start) || check.Equal(end) {
        return check.Equal(start) || check.Equal(end)
    }
    return check.After(start) && check.Before(end)
}
```

This is under the assumption the parameters we are accepting are timestamp instead of just hours and minutes